# Removing certain keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I need to create a function that removes keys if their values are duplicates in a dictionary. For example...

```
remove_dups({1:4, 2:4, 3:2})
{3:2}
remove dups({1:2, 2:5})
{1:2, 2:5}
```

I have no idea how to do this and where to start, please help!
Need to know how to do this without list comprehensions or importing.

Comment: Could perhaps be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766904/python-remove-duplicate-value-in-a-combined-dictionarys-list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_dups(d):
    c, result = {}, {}
    for item in d.values():
        c[item] = c.get(item, 0) + 1
    for k, v in d.items():
        if c[v] == 1:
            result[k] = v
    return result
```

The best and simpler way to do this would be to use `Counter` and dict comprehension like this

```
from collections import Counter
def remove_dups(d):
    c = Counter(d.values())
    return {k:v for k, v in d.items() if c[v] == 1}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I need to know how to do this without list comprehensions or importing.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries has a function - dict.values() - getting all the values as a list

{1:4, 2:4, 3:2}.values() = [4,4,2]

Then you can user counter (from collection import Counter) - check the values with count greater than 1  and remove the keys which are associated with does values.

(I don't give the complete code since it sounds like a homework assignment)

Comment: It isn't a homework assignment. I'm studying for my final exams looking at my previous exams and I got stuck on this question, I'm just trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: No problem - continuing the solution above -

def remove_dups(d):
    c = Counter(d.values())
    keys_to_remove = []
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if c[v]>1:
           keys_to_remove.append(k)
    for k in keys_to_remove:
        del(dict[k])